# WP8: PhoneApplicationPage.Resources - "Resources" is not recognized or is not accessible

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm developing my first native Windows Phone 8 application, and I'm new to xaml.

I am trying to create a resources section to contain a DataTemplate using the following markup:

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="LoopingSelectorTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="32" Foreground="Green"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

However I am getting an error 'The member "Resources" is not recognized or is not accessible.'

Am I missing a reference, or xmlns? Most search results I find seem to imply that the above markup should work out of the box, and don't mention needing anything else.

Edit:

When I try and build the solution I get the following errors:

'The member "Resources" is not recognized or is not accessible.'

"The attachable property 'Resources' was not found in type 'PhoneApplicationPage'"

and "The property 'Resources' does not exist on the type 'Grid' in the XML namespace 'clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone'"

Comment: You are doing this inside a phoneapplicationpage and not the app.xaml?

Comment: Can you show the code where the Exception is thrown? Is the error thrown by C# code og XAML Without it, it's hard to tell what goes wrong.

Comment: This is in the MainPage.xaml, so yes it's a PhoneApplicationPage. The error is syntax highlighted in the XAML, and if I try to build the solution I get the errors which I've added to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that although I was adding this to the MainPage.xaml, it wasn't at the root phone:PhoneApplicationPage tag, but instead it was within a Grid tag.